# Note that wherever a ‘;’ appears in the description of a command’s syntax, it may be replaced with one or more newlines

Tags: bash, sh

I was looking at the syntax for 'for loop in bash'. This is one of  the syntax for using for loop

```
for (( i=0; i<4; i++ )); do echo $i; done
```

I tried to replace the ";" with the new line in for loop, it gives me an error (I can only add new lines after 'do' or after echo). i.e.

```
for (( i=0
       i<4
       i++ ))
do echo $i; done
```

why do we need to have a trailing and ending white space for arithmetic expansion? What is the reason behind it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> why do we need to have a trailing and ending white space for arithmetic expansion?

Because this is the syntax of the alternate form of `for` in bash. It needs the `;`. Still:

```
for ((i=0;
i<4;
i++)); do
```

is fine.

> Note that wherever a ‘;’ appears in the description of a command’s syntax, it may be replaced with one or more newlines

Not "wherever" - you can't replace `;;` with two newlines when inside `case`. The `;` may be replaced by a newline when inside a [*list of commands*](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists):

> A sequence of one or more newlines may appear in a list to delimit commands, equivalent to a semicolon

The `((...))` is a bash extension and is not a list of commands, so, well, not there.

Comment: Exactly. To further demonstrate this, try putting a semicolon after the `i++`. You can't...but you can put a newline.

Comment: The `;;` is a distinct token from `;`. Try `echo hi ;; ls`. The  `case` construct uses a separate token deliberately. Perhaps `for ((` should have used that same token.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an oversight to me. Submit a bug report. If you include a patch, it could get in; you never know.

It makes the language inconsistent, and causes the documentation to tell lies, which is justification enough.

However, there is slight problem, because, unfortunately, constructs like the following are currently permitted:

```
# note lack of backslash line continuations

$ for (( i =
>  0 ; i <
>  5 ; i++ )) ; do echo $i ; done
0
1
2
3
4
```

The fact that newlines are allowed anywhere creates ambiguities if you want to use one or more newline as a replacement for a required semicolon.

Why the extension allows arbitrary whitespace is likely that the `$(( ))` arithmetic expansion does that:

```
$ echo $((
> 2 
> +
> 2
> ))
4
```

The three expressions enclosed in the `for (( ))` just follow arithmetic expansion syntax.

Comment: The idea is that inside arithmetic expansions the syntax follows C. You can even use the comma operator in a similar fashion as in C. The syntax is (in a posix way ;) documented, not in bash, but posix has [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap01.html#tag_01_07_02_01) `The evaluation of arithmetic expressions shall be equivalent to that described in Section 6.5, Expressions, of the ISO C standard`. The idea behind `for ((;;))` is to mimic the C `for` statement and, well,  I do not find it confusing nor inconsistent.

Comment: @KamilCuk Arithmetic expansion did not have to follow C all the way to the detail that newlines are the same as spaces.  It could have easily been a requirement that the expression occurs in a single logical line (so that backslashes must be used for continuation). That's consistent with the shell language, which requires backslashes to break up a command into multiple lines.